# Programmatically build a Visual Studio solution?

Tags: visual-studio

Is there a way to programmatically build Visual Studio solutions? E.g. if you are inside a console app, can you programmatically build an existing solution elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

devenv.exe solution.sln /build "Release"

Comment: The answer by Matt Davis is much better... msbuild is faster and allows many more options/features

Answer (score 6):

Sure- MSBuild is included on any machine with .NET 2.0 or better installed. Just call it and pass the solution file, or drive the MSBuild classes (see [Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.build.buildengine.engine.aspx)) from your code to do it.

Comment: or better yet, use CC.NET and have it continuously build your solution for you using msbuild.

Comment: Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine is not obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

You should no longer use the Microsoft.Build.BuildEngine.Engine class. Per MSDN, "This class has been deprecated. Please use Microsoft.Build.Evaluation.ProjectCollection from the Microsoft.Build assembly instead."